# Is there a way I can use docker and containerize different features of the node js application?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently working on a big project that requires many features, some features of the app will be working and sometimes, when I start another feature, I may encounter an error and the whole app will be down.

I want to know if there's a way I can create the different features of the app api seperate from each other, so that when one feature has an error, the server will not be down only the feature can be down and when i'm deploying it, it will have one base url.

That's why i'm asking if there a way I can use docker and containerize different features of the node js application am working on?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking or what the underlying issue is. Your proposed solution sounds overly-complex. How are you handling source management? Sounds like something is fundamentally broken in the dev process if broken functionality is in the main branch.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I don't know what is source management. I'm working on a project that has many features like create model for cars, edit car etc in one feature and create house model edit house etc as another feature. I want to know if is possible to create those features in isolation from one and another but in the same server. What i want is mainly for a way to stop the server from crashing if any of the features crashes or has error.

Comment: Implement better error handling? Errors shouldn't crash the server, they should be handled gracefully. If it's a single app there's no (easy) way to separate portions of that app to different servers--it's a single app. Deployed apps should rarely crash--there's a fundamental issue in the dev process if there's no source control and no management around what's being deployed.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a _microservice architecture_; it is possible, it can be significantly more complex than a single flat Node application, and it does not intrinsically require Docker or any other container technology.